# Simple SOAP request using a simple Array

Tags: arrays, soap, syntax, request

I have been searching the web for this and still i have no clue how to do it.
What I would like to know is how to write a simple request using `SOAP` in which a simple array is passed as a paremeter filled with some data.
And I dont care if it is `String array, Int array`, or whatever.

I am frustrated because something that in my opinion should be easy and surely it is a common thing when working with Soap it is so hard to find.

I still have hope, someone in the planet must know how to do this.
Help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide example of request you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Passing array as parameter to SOAP function is exactly same as passing the array as parameter to any other function.

The only care you need to take is to match the names of the keys in case of associative arrays.

For example,

I have a web-service which accepts an array of integers and returns an array filled with the squares of them. The WSDL will be similar to the one accepting and returning only integer, except for the `type` element:

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:element name="SquareRequest">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Values" type="tns:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfAnyType">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="anyType" nillable="true"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="SquareResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SquareResult" type="tns:ArrayOfAnyType"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

If you are invoking the SOAP request using PHP, then your will be something like:

```
$wsdl = "squares.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1));
$params = array('Values' => array(0, 1, 2));
$result = $client->Squares($params);
/* result can be traversed as */
foreach($result->SquareResult->anyType as $place) {
    ...
}
```